# How to prevent CompletableFuture chain from continuing down the chain when an exception is thrown?

Tags: java, completable-future

What would be the best way in the `supplyAsync` method to break out of the CompletableFuture chain when an exception is throw?

```
public static void runTask(FormattedDonut donut){
    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        try {
            return donut.requestDonuts(); 
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            System.out.println("log something..");
            // what do I call here to return without going down the chain

            
        }
    }).thenAccept(...);
```

Comment: If the triggering stage completes exceptionally then so will all its dependent stages, unless such a stage is one that can handle exceptions (e.g. `handle[Async]`, `whenComplete[Async]`, and `exceptionally[Async]`). So all you should have to do, based on the little amount of code you've provided, is throw the `NoSuchElementException` (i.e. let it propagate and fail the future).

Comment: @Slaw Thanks, I will go with `throw new CompletionException(e)`

Comment: You don’t need to wrap the `NoSuchElementException` in a `CompletionException`; that will happen automatically in the subsequent stages. Only checked exceptions need to be wrapped. The simplest approach is not to catch the exception in the first place. Just chain a log handler at the end, after the last stage.